# Clarify a definition "open set"

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

[image: Functional Analysis... kreyszig. page 18]

The definition of an open set in this book is difficult for me(see picture above).

First, What is a ball? Author has defined the open ball and closed ball. But he didn't define a ball.

Second, Let $M=[-2,2]$ be closed and $M\subset \mathbb{R}$, I will prove $M$ is also an open set by this definition. 
Proof: Show that $M$ contains a ball about each of its point.
For every $x\in M$ there is open/closed ball $B(x;r)$ for any arbitrary $r$, So each point in $M$ has a ball. What the ball does, it doesn't matter. Since the definition doesn't have any restrictions on what the open/closed ball does. For example, $B(2,2)$ contains point ${3}\not\in M$, but it dosen't matter, the definition doesn't require it. Does the definition require all the elements in the ball has to be contained in $M$? No. As long as all the points in $M$ has a ball, any ball will do, the condition is satisfied.

You may think there is something wrong there. Could you tell me that?
I am not trying to be correct, I am trying to be not-wrong. Since if I am not wrong, then I have to be correct.

Thank you for helping, it means a lot!

Comment: "contains" means is a superset of, i.e. "$A$ contains $B$" means $B \subseteq A$

Comment: Think of "open ball" as a single term. Same for "closed ball". Meaning, you could define ${\rm foo} \doteq \{ x \in X \mid d(x,x_0) < r \}$, but you'd like a more suggestive name for the object.

Comment: Ball is a set of elements that lie either inside a sphere or inside and on a sphere if that makes sense. In the definitions you "Open Ball" and "Closed Ball" you will see that the balls have inequalities in the definition but a sphere only has equality. This is analogous to the definitions of a circle and a disk. Elements on a circle would be those that lie on the circumference. However, a disk would have elements on the circumference and inside. I'm speaking very loosely here to provide some intuition.

Comment: It does not matter, but assume the author said "open ball" instead of "ball". The author could just as well have said "open or closed ball", or even "closed ball", and you'd have gotten the same notion.

Comment: "So each point in $M$ has a ball." So what? The definition of open set that you quoted doesn't say that $M$ ***has*** a ball about each of its points, it says that $M$ ***contains*** a ball about each of its points. "Does the definition require all the elements in the ball to be contained in $M$?" I think so. If $M$ ***contains*** a ball about the point $x_0,$ doesn't that mean that the ball ***is contained*** in $M$? And doesn't that mean that all points in the ball are in $M$?

Comment: Also, you can't require a set to be open or closed. You write "Let M be closed..." but this is not up to you. A set is either closed or it isn't.

Comment: I dk whether your text mentions it, but in general we cannot speak of  $the$  center or  $ the$ radius of an open ball or of a closed ball.  We can have $B(x,r)=B(x',r')$ with $x\ne x'$ and positive unequal $r, r'$.

Comment: I've got the answer, It turns out I misunderstand the word "contain". I thought It will be sufficient just contain the center. Apparently, It is not true. Thank your guys!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ball is either an open ball or a closed ball.  For the definition of open set it doesn't matter which you take because inside every closed ball is an open ball and inside every open ball is a closed ball-just decrease the radius.  Your proof that $M$ is open fails because neither $-2$ nor $2$ have a ball around them that is in $M$.  Each point in $M$ has a ball around it in $\Bbb R$, but not in $M$.  On the other hand, $(-2,2)$ is open because every point in it is some distance from $-2$ and $2$.  If you take the minimum of those two distances and cut it in half, your point has a ball around it that is part of the set.

Comment: Hi, I agree that "neither $-2$ nor $2$ have a ball around them that is in $M$". But the definition of the open ball in this book doesn't seem to require it.

Comment: The definition of an open set requires the ball to be within the set.

Comment: If you're thinking of the possibility that $r=0$, note that the definition of open ball specifically requires $r>0$.